# How to speed up a "for" loop when indexing with a list? (Python)

Tags: python, performance, numpy, loops, vectorization

I try to speed this code by using Numpy functions or vectors instead of the for loop:

```
sommes = []
for j in range(vertices.shape[0]):
    terme = new_vertices[j] - new_vertices[vertex_neighbors[j]]
    somme_j = np.sum(terme)
    sommes.append(somme_j)
E_int = np.sum(sommes)
```

(it is part of a iterated algorithm and there are a lot of "vertices", so I think the for loop takes too long.)

For example, to compute "terme" when j = 0, I have:

```
In: new_vertices[0]
Out: array([ 10.2533888 , -42.32279717,  68.27230793])

In: vertex_neighbors[0]
Out: [1280, 2, 1511, 511, 1727, 1887, 759, 509, 1023]

In: new_vertices[vertex_neighbors[0]]
Out: array([[ 10.47121043, -42.00123956,  68.218715  ],
            [ 10.2533888 , -43.26905874,  62.59473849],
            [ 10.69773735, -41.26464083,  68.09594854],
            [ 10.37030712, -42.16729601,  68.24639107],
            [ 10.12158146, -42.46624547,  68.29621598],
            [  9.81850836, -42.71158695,  68.33710623],
            [  9.97615447, -42.59625943,  68.31788497],
            [ 10.37030712, -43.11676015,  62.54960623],
            [ 10.55512696, -41.82622703,  68.18954624]])

In: new_vertices[0] - new_vertices[vertex_neighbors[0]]
Out: array([[-0.21782162, -0.32155761,  0.05359293],
             [ 0.        ,  0.94626157,  5.67756944],
             [-0.44434855, -1.05815634,  0.17635939],
             [-0.11691832, -0.15550116,  0.02591686],
             [ 0.13180734,  0.1434483 , -0.02390805],
             [ 0.43488044,  0.38878979, -0.0647983 ],
             [ 0.27723434,  0.27346227, -0.04557704],
             [-0.11691832,  0.79396298,  5.7227017 ],
             [-0.30173816, -0.49657014,  0.08276169]])
```

The problem is that new_vertices[vertex_neighbors[j]] doesn't always have the same size. For example, when j = 7:

```
In: new_vertices[7]
Out: array([ 10.74106112, -63.88592276, -70.15593947])

In: vertex_neighbors[7]
Out: [1546, 655, 306, 1879, 920, 925]

In: new_vertices[vertex_neighbors[7]]
Out: array([[  9.71830698, -69.07323638, -83.10229623],
           [ 10.71123017, -64.06983438, -70.09345104],
           [  9.74836003, -68.88820555, -83.16187474],
           [ 10.78982867, -63.70552665, -70.2169896 ],
           [  9.74627177, -60.87823935, -60.13032811],
           [  9.79419242, -60.69528267, -60.182843  ]])

In: new_vertices[7] - new_vertices[vertex_neighbors[7]]
Out: array([[  1.02275414,   5.18731363,  12.94635676],
             [  0.02983095,   0.18391163,  -0.06248843],
             [  0.99270108,   5.0022828 ,  13.00593527],
             [ -0.04876756,  -0.18039611,   0.06105013],
             [  0.99478934,  -3.00768341, -10.02561137],
             [  0.94686869,  -3.19064009,  -9.97309648]])
```

Is it possible without the for loop? I'm running out of ideas, so any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, this is possible. The idea is to use `np.repeat` to create a vector where the items are repeated a variable number of times.
Here is the code:

```py
# The two following lines can be done only once if the indices are constant between iterations (precomputation)
counts = np.array([len(e) for e in vertex_neighbors])
flatten_indices = np.concatenate(vertex_neighbors)

E_int = np.sum(np.repeat(new_vertices, counts, axis=0) - new_vertices[flatten_indices])
```

---

Here is a benchmark:

```py
import numpy as np
from time import *


n = 32768
vertices = np.random.rand(n, 3)
indices = []

count = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n)

for i in range(n):
    indices.append(np.random.randint(0, n, size=count[i]))

def initial_version(vertices, vertex_neighbors):
    sommes = []
    for j in range(vertices.shape[0]):
        terme = vertices[j] - vertices[vertex_neighbors[j]]
        somme_j = np.sum(terme)
        sommes.append(somme_j)
    return np.sum(sommes)

def optimized_version(vertices, vertex_neighbors):
    # The two following lines can be precomputed
    counts = np.array([len(e) for e in indices])
    flatten_indices = np.concatenate(indices)

    return np.sum(np.repeat(vertices, counts, axis=0) - vertices[flatten_indices])

def more_optimized_version(vertices, vertex_neighbors, counts, flatten_indices):
    return np.sum(np.repeat(vertices, counts, axis=0) - vertices[flatten_indices])

timesteps = 20

a = time()
for t in range(timesteps):
    res = initial_version(vertices, indices)
b = time()
print("V1: time:", b - a)
print("V1: result", res)

a = time()
for t in range(timesteps):
    res = optimized_version(vertices, indices)
b = time()
print("V2: time:", b - a)
print("V2: result", res)

a = time()
counts = np.array([len(e) for e in indices])
flatten_indices = np.concatenate(indices)
for t in range(timesteps):
    res = more_optimized_version(vertices, indices, counts, flatten_indices)
b = time()
print("V3: time:", b - a)
print("V3: result", res)
```

Here is the benchmark result on my machine:

```
V1: time: 3.656714916229248
V1: result -395.8416223057596
V2: time: 0.19800186157226562
V2: result -395.8416223057595
V3: time: 0.07983255386352539
V3: result -395.8416223057595
```

As you can see, this optimized version is 18 times faster than the reference implementation and the one that precompute the indices is 46 times faster than the reference implementation.

Note that the optimized version should require more RAM (especially if the number of neighbors per vertex is big).